# Why I can write into a file which I don't have permission to?

Tags: permissions, vim

```
user1@server1:/locdisk/data/a$ touch test
user1@server1:/locdisk/data/a$ ll

rwxrwxrwx 1 user1 user1 1 AUG 30 11:11 ./
rwx------ 1 user1 user1 1 AUG 30 11:11 test

user2@server2:~$ ssh server1
user2@server1:~$ vi /locdisk/data/a/test
```

And then modify test by 'w!'

```
user2@server1:~$ ll /locdisk/data/a/

rwxrwxrwx 1 user1 user1 1 AUG 30 11:11 ./  
rwx------ 1 user2 user2 3 AUG 30 11:11 test
```

How could it be??

My Ubuntu has a bug? How should I fix it?

Comment: Related (maybe a duplicate) [Why can I modify a read-only file?](//askubuntu.com/q/815838)